# ClusterKey Attribute in DataStax C# Driver

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

I have been trying to get a test object mapping working using the attributes in the Datastax C# driver for Cassandra.
There is a table in cassandra defined by

```
CREATE TABLE test.omfieldtest (
    integer int,
    bigint varint,
    stringtext text, 
    universal uuid, 
    bool boolean, 
    singleprecision float,
    variableprecision decimal,
    PRIMARY KEY ((integer), bigint, stringtext, universal)
);
```

I then have a decorated C# class to map to that table

```
[Table("test.omfieldtest")]
    public class MappingTest
    {
        [PartitionKey]
        public Int32 integer;
        [ClusteringKey(0, SortOrder.Ascending, Name = "bigint")]
        public Int64 bigint;
        [ClusteringKey(1, SortOrder.Ascending, Name = "stringtext")]
        public string stringVal;
        [ClusteringKey(2, SortOrder.Ascending, Name = "universal")]
        public Guid universal;
        [Column("bool")]
        public bool boolVal;
        [Column("singleprecision")]
        public Single singlePrecisionVal;
        [Column("variableprecision")]
        public decimal variablePrecisionVal;
    }
```

Upon using `mapper.Insert<MappingTest>`, an InvalidQueryException is thrown with the problem of an "Unknown identifier stringval".If I change the name of the property to match the column name, everything works fine, regardless of what the Name property of the `ClusterKey` is set to.

So then what is the purpose or even the effect of specifying the Name property for the `ClusterKey` attribute?

Comment: Are you using the attributes under the `Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes` namespace or the deprecated Linq attributes?

Comment: They are the ones from the `Cassandra.Mapping.Attributes` namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you've hit a driver bug in the Mapper/Linq components. I've created a ticket to track it: [CSHARP-507](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-507)

Luckily, there's a workaround: including the `ColumnAttribute` along with the clustering key, in your case would be:

```
[Column("stringtext")]
[ClusteringKey]
public string stringVal;
```

I've also included a failing test in the repository: https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver/commit/9917bfff4ef569525a6df845f35d31d817e79dc0